# Check whether the type of a variable is a specific type in Python

Tags: python

I want to check whether the type of a variable is a specific kind in Python. For example- I want to check if var `x` is an int or not.

```
>>x=10
>>type(x)
<type 'int'>
```

But how can I compare their types. I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
if type(10)== "<type 'int'>":
    print 'yes'
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: It is worth noting that explicitly checking -- and branching on -- variable types is widely considered un-Pythonic since it's a direct violation of duck typing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`isinstance()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) to test for a specific type:

```
isinstance(x, int)
```

`isinstance()` takes either a single type, or a tuple of types to test against:

```
isinstance(x, (float, complex, int))
```

would test for a series of different numeric types for example.

Comment: Worth to note, you can also use a tuple instead of a type and then it will return True if the variable is of ANY of the types given in the tuple, for example: `isinstance(x, (int, float, decimal))` would return True if `x` is an int, or a float, or a decimal.

Comment: @InbarRose: Indeed; I always use `complex` as an example for that one. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Your example could be written as:

```
if type(10) is int: # "==" instead of "is" would also work.
    print 'yes'
```

But note that it might not exactly do what you want, for example, if you wrote `10L` or a number greater than [`sys.maxint`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.maxint) instead of just `10`, this would not print yes, because `long` (which would be the type of such a number) is not `int`.

Another way is, as Martijn already suggested, to use the [`isinstance()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) builtin function as follows:

```
if isinstance(type(10), int):
    print 'yes'
```

`insinstance(instance, Type)` returns `True` not only if `type(instance) is Type` but also if instance's type is derived from `Type`. So, since `bool` is a subclass of `int` this would also work for `True` and `False`.

But generally it is better not to check for specific types, but for for the features, you need. That is, if your code can't handle the type, it will automatically throw an exception when trying to perform an unsupported operation on the type.

If you, however, need to handle e.g. integers and floating-point numbers differently, you might want to check for `isinstance(var, numbers.Integral)` (needs `import numbers`) which evalutes to `True` if `var` is of type `int`, `long`, `bool` or any user-defined type which is derived from this class. See the Python documenation on [the standard type hierarchy](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) and [`numbers` module]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following ways:

```
>>> isinstance('ss', str)
True
>>> type('ss')
<class 'str'>
>>> type('ss') == str
True
>>>
```

int - > Integer

float -> Floating Point Value

list -> List

tuple -> Tuple

dict -> Dictionary

For classes it is a little different:
Old type classes:

```
>>> # We want to check if cls is a class
>>> class A:
        pass
>>> type(A)
<type 'classobj'>
>>> type(A) == type(cls)  # This should tell us
```

New type classes:

```
>>> # We want to check if cls is a class
>>> class B(object):
        pass
>>> type(B)
<type 'type'>
>>> type(cls) == type(B)  # This should tell us


>>> #OR
>>> type(cls) == type # This should tell us
```