# How to split Python lists automatically based on type?

Tags: python

Before I begin, I've tried looking for this in other places, but found nothing, so please be gentle.

I'm trying to use a simple for loop to split a list into two lists based on the type of the data.

I want to separate strings from everything else.

This is what I have so far:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, "Missing1", 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "Missing2", 10]

new_list = []
str_list = []
i = 0

for i in list1:
    if type(int):
        new_list.append(i)
    elif type(float):
        new_list.append(i)
    else:
        str_list.append(i)


print(new_list)
print(str_list)
```

But my result is this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'Missing1', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'Missing2', 10]
[]
```

It seems Python is viewing those strings as integers -- how do I change that?

Comment: The condition `if type(int):` cannot possibly check whether the value `i` is an `int`, because the variable `i` doesn't appear in the condition at all.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187038/check-whether-the-type-of-a-variable-is-a-specific-type-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some errors in your code. Here it is fixed.

```py
new_list = []
str_list = []

for i in list1:
    if type(i) == int:
        new_list.append(i)
    elif type(i) == float:
        new_list.append(i)
    else:
        str_list.append(i)
```

Here's a more generalizable splitting list code:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

lists = defaultdict(list)
for i in list1:
   lists[type(x)].append(i)
```

Now, `lists[int]`, `lists[float]`, and `lists[str]` will all provide lists of its own type.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense that it should look at each index individually. Also, your alternative method there is very clean!